# MVC update model parameter value in button onclick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

Is it possible to update a model parameter value in a button onclick without having to write javascript code ? something like

```
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Re-Open" onclick="Model.PatientChartStatusId = 12"/>
</td>
```

What would be the correct syntax ?

Many thanks

Comment: What kind of MVC do you have? Does the model have a setter method for `PatientChartStatusId`?

Comment: MVC 4 , Yes  
Thanks